# Typescript extend/replace return type of built-in type typeof

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Is there a way to extend the returns type of the token `typeof` using typescript?

With typescript i can extend build-in types like the following:

```
interface String{
    myMethod: any;
}
```

it seems there's no obvious /simple way of extending `typeof`.

Comment: How would you like to extend it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done.

Extending types of the standard library (like `String`) is something that can sometimes be useful, but changing how the type systems keywords work isn't something typescript supports at all.

Comment: Ok thanks, going to edit the language service / add some plugin